# WebSecurity Configurer Class Spring Boot Not Working as required... No other WebSecurity Configurer in project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller

```
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login.jsp")
            .failureUrl("/login.jsp?error=1").loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .permitAll().and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout.jsp").invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/listEmployees.html");

}
```

On hitting on /logout.jso session and cookies are not cleared

Comment: Please make your question more clear and enrich your content.

Comment: While Using  configurer method of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter only the authentication is done .. Session Management is not performed i.e Cookies are not deleted nor session is invalidated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your logout config, remove the ".jsp" of logout, try this:

```
logout.logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).invalidateHttp...
```

And in your button of logout, just add:

```
href="/logout" (just it)
```

Comment: then add this annotation to your security class, or in your service class that make the login: @Scope(value="session", proxyMode= ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)